# Invalid request: More than one field cannot be used to specify a sender

Tags: paypal, paypal-adaptive-payments

I'm just getting started with Paypal API's to make to a P2P payment using the classic API.

The response is the following error:

> Invalid request: More than one field cannot be used to specify a
> sender.

#### The request

```
  {requestEnvelope.errorLanguage=en_US&actionType=CREATE&cancelUrl=http%3A%2F%2Flocalhost%3A8080%2Fadaptivepaymentssample-2.4.103%2Findex.html¤cyCode=USD&receiverList.receiver(0).amount=2.0&receiverList.receiver(0).email=fsd.7-facilitator%40gmail.com&receiverList.receiver(0).primary=true&receiverList.receiver(0).paymentType=PERSONAL&senderEmail=sdasdsad-facilitator%40gmail.com&returnUrl=http%3A%2F%2Flocalhost%3A8080%2Fadaptivepaymentssample-2.4.103%2Findex.html&sender.useCredentials=true&}
```

#### The response

```
{responseEnvelope.timestamp=2013-10-09T11%3A01%3A37.639-07%3A00&responseEnvelope.ack=Failure&responseEnvelope.correlationId=32d5c266f19b1&responseEnvelope.build=7935900&error(0).errorId=580001&error(0).domain=PLATFORM&error(0).subdomain=Application&error(0).severity=Error&error(0).category=Application&error(0).message=Invalid+request%3A+More+than+one+field+cannot+be+used+to+specify+a+sender}
```

Anyone knows what could be causing this issue?